# Calling a javascript function in iFrame opened with Fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, parameter-passing, function-calls

I'm trying to call a javascript function in a page opened in an iFrame using jQuery Fancybox.

```
            $(".testbox").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                afterShow: function() {
                        //var frameID = $('#fancybox-frame')
                        //frameID.getParam("test");                         
                    }
            }); 

        $(".testbox").each(function() {
                var element = this;
                $(this).fancybox({
                    'titleFormat'   : function() {
                        var astring = '<span>' + element.id + '</span>';
                        alert(astring);
                    }
                });
            });
```

HTML:

```
    <a class="testbox fancybox.iframe" href="include/testFrame.html">Iframe</a>
```

The function in the testFrame.html I'm trying to call:

```
        function getParam(param) {              
            alert(param);               
        }
```

Normally I'd do this when calling functions in iFrame without using a Fancybox popup:

```
        document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.getParam();
```

but I don't know how to get the ID of the whole iFrame when using Fancybox. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** 
I also tried this code which also didn't work, I get the error in IE: Object doesn't support this property or method. I've made sure the page I'm loading has the function

```
    var $f = $("#fancybox-frame");
    var fd = $f[0].document || $f[0].contentWindow.document; 
    fd.getparam("test");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
var $f = $("#fancybox-frame");
$f[0].contentWindow.getParam("test");
```

Reasons:

- The method is globally declared, not as a method of the `document` object.
- JavaScript is case-sensitive; `getParam` is distinct from `getparam`.